# Changing matplotlib window title is throwing strange error

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using python 3.6 in Jupyter lab on a linux mint machine to run this snippet of code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
man = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
man.window.setWindowTitle("New Title")
```

..it returns the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'FigureManagerBase' object has no attribute 'window'
```

I have checked the GUI backends. All are available and all of them return this error even if I force the backend using ...

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use(<gui>,warn=False, force=True)
```

...before importing pyplot. The code has been working OK in Spyder but I've had to move to Jupyter. The matplotlib docs say that FigureManagerBase attributes include 'window'. I'm stumped

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the window title, use the code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
man = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
man.canvas.set_window_title("New Title")
```

Comment: *MatplotlibDeprecationWarning*

The set_window_title function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.4 and will be removed two minor releases later. Use `.FigureManagerBase.set_window_title` or GUI-specific methods instead.
**man.set_window_title("New Title")** is correct

Comment: This works `fig.canvas.manager.set_window_title("Hello world")`

Answer (score 2):

Using python 3.8, matplotlib 3.5.3 the following works for me:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

man = plt.get_current_fig_manager()

man.set_window_title("New Title")
```